# BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions) returns FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to display picture captured through camera intent (triggering inbuilt camera app) which is stored in `external SD-card`.

The file path and file name is stored in String variable `'mCurrentPhotoPath'`.

I have verified that the image captured is stored in the location specified by `'mCurrentPhotoPath'` using `ES File Explorer` app, but the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions)` is always returning `FileNotFoundException`. Here is my code to store the captured image:

```
    private void addPicToGallery() {

    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    //for debug purpose only
    Log.i(MYTAG, "value of mCurrentPhotoPath in addPicToGallery: " +mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Log.i(MYTAG, "value of f in addPicToGallery:  " +f);

    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

    //for debug only
    Log.i(MYTAG, "value of contentUri in addPicToGallery: " +contentUri);

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new    Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

}
```

Code for decoding a scaled image for display in `ImageView`:

```
    private void setFullImageFromFilePath() {

    Log.i(MYTAG, "Entered setFullImageFromFilePath method");

    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    Log.i(MYTAG,"var targetW in setFullImageFromFilePath is:"  +targetW);
    Log.i(MYTAG,"the targetH in setFullImageFromFilePath is:" + targetH);


    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Log.i(MYTAG, "the mCurrentPhotoPath in setFullImageFromFilePath is:" + mCurrentPhotoPath);


   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW= bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    //Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    //Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the view
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) ;

    }
```

However, `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` is not able to find the file at the location stored in `mCurrentPhotoPath` resulting in `FileNotFoundException`.

Following is the *LogCat* output:

```
>07-20 21:28:11.897  32301-32301/org.assignment.lab.Pic I/Lab-Intents﹕ the mCurrentPhotoPath in setFullImageFromFilePath is:file:/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20150720_212749_-232171051.jpg
07-20 21:28:11.907  32301-32301/org.assignment.lab.Pic E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20150720_212749_-232171051.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-20 21:28:11.937  32301-32301/org.assignment.lab.Pic D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-20 21:28:11.937  32301-32301/org.assignment.lab.Pic W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418d0ce0)
07-20 21:28:12.047  32301-32301/org.assignment.lab.Pic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.assignment.lab.Pic, PID: 32301
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {org.assignment.lab.mydailyselfie/org.coursera.assignment.lab.Pic.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

I am debugging this application in `Android Kitkat 4.4.4` phone.

Please suggest what modification needed in `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method so that it can get the file stored and display it in `ImageView`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `mCurrentPhotoPath` has a prefix "`file:`".

Because of which the system is trying to refer to `/file:/storage/sdcard0/etc...` which points to no mounted disk.

Remove that and try again with

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = "/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20150720_212749_-232171051.jpg";
```

Or, if your `mCurrentPhotoPath` will always have the prefix, do this before using it

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = mCurrentPhotoPath.replace("file:", "");
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. After removing "file:" prefix, the problem was solved. Btw, this code is straight from developer.android.com. Now I wonder if this prefix was necessary in older android version. Thanks again.